# Android Studio Dolphin missing VCS menu

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.1

I can no longer find **"Enable Version Control Integration"** which is under VCS tab in Android Studio, looks like it was replace with Git but I can't see a way to enable version control with the new options. Does anyone know where to enable it or how can we quickly enable VCS in a project?

I am using **Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Canary 7**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Menu, named `Git`, it means you are already have **Git** repository initialized for the project. You can check this in Settings/Preferences | Version Control | **Directory Mappings** settings. See [Set up a Git repository﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html) for the steps.

Comment: I do have but that is a submodule for library not the project itself.

Comment: I figure it out, there is also an option to create a repository via Git tab at the bottom.